# New hash from existing hash within list - Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a list that contains hashes that looks similar to this:

```
list = [{"created_at"=>"2016-11-07T18:49:51.000Z",
         "updated_at"=>"2016-11-07T18:49:51.000Z",
         "id"=>1,
         "name"=>"Test1",
         "title"=>"Test1",
         "description"=>""},
        {"created_at"=>"2017-05-24T13:34:13.000Z",
         "updated_at"=>"2017-05-24T13:34:13.000Z",
         "id"=>23,
         "name"=>"Test2",
         "title"=>"Test2",
         "description"=>nil}]
```

I want to be able to iterate over this list of hashes and create a new hash that only has the id's value as a key, and the name's value as the value of the key.  Currently my solution is this:

```
def new_hash(list)
  @new_hash = Hash.new
  list.each do | x |
    @new_hash[x["id"]] = x["name"]
  end
end
```

This produces a hash like this:

`{1=>"Test1", 23=>"Test2"}`

My question is, is there a more elegant way to approach this in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
Hash[list.map { |h| h.values_at('id', 'name') }]
 => {1=>"Test1", 23=>"Test2"}
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know you could call Hash like that.  That reads much nicer.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["id"]] = g["name"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
list.map {|hash| [hash["id"], hash["name"]]}.to_h
#=> {1=>"Test1", 23=>"Test2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {name: 'akshay', last_name: 'kakade'}
new_hash = Hash[data]
data.object_id
new_hash.object_id
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.